# Prove $x^{2n} + x^{2n-1}y + x^{2n-2}y^2 + \ldots + y^{2n} \geq 0$

Tags: inequality

This is trivial if there are binomial coefficients, but I don't know how to transform that case into this one. Obviously one can assume $xy < 0$ and then without loss of generality let $x$ be positive so you consider $(x-y)^6$, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: As a hint: Consider a factorisation of $x^{2n+1}-y^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}y+\cdots+xy^{2n-1}+y^{2n}\ge 0$$

$$\stackrel{x\neq y}\iff \frac{x^{2n+1}-y^{2n+1}}{x-y}\ge 0,$$

which is true because $x^{2n+1}-y^{2n+1}$ and $x-y$ have the same signs.

If $x=y$, then $\iff (2n+1)x^{2n}\ge 0$, which is true.